# Force a program (video game) to continue working when minimized?

Tags: windows, script, gaming, pause

I play a video game (Stronghold Crusader) and when I minimize it, it pauses. I mean when I maximize it again, I continue from where I left.

For some minutes, you're just doing nothing (maybe waiting for some resources to be collected). I want in these minutes to minimize it and maybe check the Facebook or whatever and let it continues.

***So, is there a way (a script or anything) to force the game to continue working even when I minimize it?***

Comment: Why not just not minimize it and move it to the corner of a screen so only a tiny bit shows up?

Comment: Technically speaking, I can't minimize it. I just press *win* key or *Alt* + *Tab*

Comment: It is trivial to pause your main thread as a programming, if the application's window isn't the current widow which has focus, so if the application doesn't support window mode you are out luck because there isn't a way around that trivial amount of code